# Sumproduct matching values in excel

Tags: excel

I have two excel tables:

```
    A       B       C       D       E
1   John    10              Mark    2
2   Tommy   20              Tommy   3
3   Jane    15              John    4
4                           Kate    2
5                           Jane    1
```

Is there a function to sumproduct values in colum B with those values in column E which match by name, i.e. 10*4 + 20*3 + 15*1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sumif` for this and just sum up the results when you are done:

```
=B1 * sumif(D:D, A1, E:E)
```

Copy that down your sheet, and then add up the totals.

If you don't want a ton of formulas hanging out on your sheet, you could convert this to a CSE/Array formula:

```
=SUM($B$1:$B$3*SUMIF(D:D, $A$1:$A$3,E:E ))
```

Just enter that in and hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter it. It will get curly braces around it, which means it's an Array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about sumproduct, we could use SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$5=A1)*$B$1:$B$5)*SUMPRODUCT(($D$1:$D$5=A1)*$E$1:$E$5)
```

Now that is assuming there are no repeats (all names are unique).  In the event that names are not unique you will have those numbers added together then multiplied.

After you apply that to a column and copied down appropriately, lets say F1 to F3,  in F5 you could get your final answer using:

```
=SUM(F1:F3)
```